# How can I implement a function that gets rid of reduntant Objets inside an Array of Objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object, local-storage

So I am trying to implement a function that allows me to stock locally details of a couch inside a JS object with 3 properties:

- **An ID** (which is covered with the URL of the product through a function)
- **A color** (which is recovered thanks to an event listener)
- **A quantity** (which is recovered the same way as a color)

I already have the function that allows me to stock objects locally with an array:

```js
function addedToCart(productObject) {
  let listOfProducts = getProducts();
  listOfProducts.push(productObject);
  registerProducts(listOfProducts);
}


function getProducts() {
  let listOfProducts = localStorage.getItem("listOfProducts");
  if (listOfProducts == null) {
    return [];
  } else {
    return JSON.parse(listOfProducts);
  }
}

function registerProducts(listOfProducts) {
  localStorage.setItem("listOfProducts", JSON.stringify(listOfProducts));
}
```

To finish, I have a 3 event listeners:

1. To listen when the user selects an option and get the value of the color
2. To listen to the change of the `<input type="number"/>` and get the value of the quantity
3. To listen when the user clicks on the "Add to cart" button

Here's my code in JS

```js
class classProductCartDetails {
  constructor(id, color, quantity) {
    this.id = id;
    this.color = color;
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }
}

let quantityProduct = document.getElementById("quantity");
let valid = true;

let colorValue = 0;
let quantityValue = 0;


itemColors.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  colorValue = event.target.value;
  console.log(colorValue);
});



quantityProduct.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  quantityValue = event.target.value;
  console.log(quantityValue);
});






addToCartButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (quantityValue > 0 && quantityValue <= 100 && colorValue != 0) {
    let objectProduct = new classProductCartDetails(
      productId,
      colorValue,
      quantityValue
    );

    console.table(objectProduct);

    alert("Your product has been added to the cart!");
    addedToCart(objectProduct);
  }
  if(colorValue == 0 && quantityValue <= 0){
alert("WARNING! You must add the details of the product");
  }
else if (colorValue == 0) {
    alert("WARNING! You must add a color");
}
 else if (quantityValue <= 0) {
    alert("WARNING! The quantity inputted is invalid");
  }
  
});
```

The problem? If I just **click twice on the "Add to cart"** button or if I **change the quantity of the couch then click the button**, it's going to add a **redundant** new object instance to the array!

```json
[{id: "107fb5b75607497b96722bda5b504926", color: "White", quantity: "1"},…]
0: {id: "107fb5b75607497b96722bda5b504926", color: "White", quantity: "1"}
1: {id: "107fb5b75607497b96722bda5b504926", color: "Blue", quantity: "1"}
2: {id: "107fb5b75607497b96722bda5b504926", color: "Blue", quantity: "1"}
3: {id: "107fb5b75607497b96722bda5b504926", color: "Blue", quantity: "2"}
```

As you can see, we have 3 times the same object, 2 that are the same and one that has a different quantity.

And I want to implement a function that allows me to check individually the ID, color and quantity of an object with those of another object in the array.

*With these conditions:*

- If the ID, Color and Quantity are the same → Delete the redundant object in
  question
- If only the ID and the Color are the same but the quantity is
  different → Replace the value of quantity of the non-redundant with the latest value which is on the redundant object and delete the redundant object

For instance, the first object properties with the second, then with the third... then the second object with the first, the second with the third one... and so on and so forth until the last object of the array.

**English isn't my native language**, so you might not understand what I meant to say, but no worries, so here's a visual representation with this photo:
***Also TD:DR***

[image: Visual representation of the function I want to implement]
*Words in picture:*

-*No redundancy*

-*Redundancy detected:*

*1. Eliminated object with index 2 and 3*

*2. Changed the quantity of object with index 1 from 1 to 2*

And that would be the result in JSON on the local storage:

```json
[{id: "107fb5b75607497b96722bda5b504926", color: "White", quantity: "1"},…]
0: {id: "107fb5b75607497b96722bda5b504926", color: "White", quantity: "1"}
1: {id: "107fb5b75607497b96722bda5b504926", color: "Blue", quantity: "2"}
```

I've already looked at some posts on how to get rid of redundant objects in an array but they were static arrays

Is it possible to implement such a function (either through recursion or iteration)? Is it too far-fetched? Are there easier ways to get rid of redundant objects inside an array?

Any help would be appreciated

Btw if you have any recommendations to give me on my code OR have any question on my code, don't hesitate!

Comment: Can you provide code for your `addedToCart` function please.

Comment: The code of the `addedToCart` is within the 1st block of code on the top of my post, though it is lenghty so here's the code: 
`
function addedToCart(productObject) {
  let listOfProducts = getProducts();
  listOfProducts.push(productObject);
  registerProducts(listOfProducts);
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```js
function addedToCart(productObject) {
  let listOfProducts = getProducts();
  listOfProducts = listOfProducts.filter(({productId, colorValue})=> {
    return !(productId == productObject.productId && colorValue == productObject.colorValue);
  })
  listOfProducts.push(productObject);
  registerProducts(listOfProducts);
}
```

With this, if productId and colorValue are same, the previous entry is removed from the list. It will be replace by the new productObject. Whether quantity is same or not does not really matter: in all cases, you want to take the quantity from productObject.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I have a question, so I noticed that in your arrow function you have inside your parameter  2 values between curly brackets.

 I'm aware that you can group properties of an object inside curly brackets i.e.: 
`const {name, price, description} = couchProduct`

But I don't understand the use of curly brackets inside the parameters of a function, may I know why please?

Comment: @LePhenix47, it is the same principle as in `const {name, price, description} = couchProduct`. Here `({productId, colorValue})=> {...` is like doing `(arg) => { let {productId, colorValue} = arg; ...`. Convenient...

Comment: I would think you'd want to add productObject.quantity to the matching listOfProducts entry's quantity property if that product already exists in the list.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found a solution:

```js
  let verifyProducts = (objectToVerify, arrayOfObjects) => {
    let verifyProduct = arrayOfObjects.find((object) => { 
    const {id, color} = objectToVerify;

   object.id === id && object.color === color
    }); 
  
    if(verifyProduct){
      verifyProduct.quantity = Number(objectToVerify.quantity);
    }else{
      arrayOfObjects.push(objectToVerify);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go ... pass your array to the function and the function will return an array with the redundant objects deleted.

we basically iterate through the array starting at index 0 (so the oldest entries first).

For each index we check, if the combination of our current objects' id and color exists further along in the array (which if true would mean one of two things:

- it exists an object, that has the same id, color and quantity
- or an object exists, that has the same id and color but different quantity

and since we only compare against objects that are "newer" than our current object, both cases would mean, that the object at our current index is redundant ... so we just delete it.

after our loop we tidy up our array by removing all those indexes which are now undefined

If you were to implement that code from the start and using it every time when adding a new object, you could get away with only checking against the last object

```js
const arr = [{id : 1, color : "black", quantity: 1}, 
           {id : 1, color : "black", quantity: 1},
           {id : 1, color : "black", quantity: 2},
           {id : 2, color : "black", quantity: 1}];
           
           
function getRidOfRedundant(arr) {
    let newArr = [...arr] //creating shallow copy of arr
    let compare = newArr.map(x => x.id + x.color);
    for (let i = 0; i < compare.length; i++) {
        if(compare.includes(compare[i], i + 1)) {
            delete (newArr[i])
        }

    }
    return newArr.filter(x => x !== undefined)
}


console.log(getRidOfRedundant(arr))
```

there is also the possibility to intervene directly at object creation. Have a condition in your constructor function, that replaces the object in the array when id and color are the same (I'm using static Properties of the class here, since using "outside" variables/objects in the constructor can be kinda sketchy) - don't know though how this would interact/work with your localStorage stuff

and you could also just take the logic stuff from the constructor and create a function, that does basically the same thing (finding index of now redundant object and overwrite it with the newly created Object)

```js
class Product {

    static memory = [];
    static objects = []

    constructor(id, color, quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.color = color;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        
        if (Product.memory.includes(id + color)) {
            Product.objects[Product.memory.indexOf(id + color)] = this;
        } else {
            Product.memory.push(id + color);
            Product.objects.push(this);
        }
    }
}

new Product(id, color, quantity)
```